# How to get GPU Energy cost in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, energy

My unity game is getting very hot quickly, So I use XCode Energy Impact to test the energy use for it on iPhone8. In Debugging Gauges, Click Energy impact, I can get the following data: CPU for  45%, Network for 10%, Overhead for 45%, Location for 0%, GPU for 0%.

Location is OK because I don't use it. But Why GPU is 0%?

Click FPS, My game run for FPS 60.  CPU cost 16.6ms, GPU cost 5.2ms.
I want to compare the energy consumption of CPU and GPU, but 0% for GPU is obvious wrong, how to  fix it and get correct data?

And, I can't find Energy Log in my Instruments, How can I find and use it?